# I want to show a multi floor indoor map in ios using swift

Tags: ios, swift, indoor-positioning-system, google-indoor-maps

I would like to create an indoor navigation app. But I have some trouble with a floor plan. I have location beacons to identify and detect user's position. I don't want to do estimate like a 3rd party tool it will be costly. Now I have troubles with.

1. Drawing floor plans
2. Showing routes `a` to `b`.
3. Scaling of map like zooming.
4. I have lengthy or big floor, plan how to manage.
5. Tagging info on clicking on of the part of map show up the info box.

Can you please suggest how to keep floor plan and routes and distances coordinate position.

Comment: hey did find any solution for this?

Comment: yes follow the solution.

Comment: @arf where is the solution..i am not using beacons

Comment: without beacon we can't locate person

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799033/how-to-access-the-object-of-navigation-graph-in-spritekit-scene-editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently worked on the indoor navigation project based on beacons. These are the things you have to keep in mind for the questions you asked.

1. You need the floor plan image or layout image for each of the floors.
2. For showing route, you have to know some algorithms to achieve the expected result. I used Dijikstra algorithm to plot the route between two points.
3. For scaling and zooming you have delegate methods in `UIScrollViewDelegate`
4. Based on the resolution of the image you have to present it.
5. Customize the info view on click.

You have to dig deep to make your project work. Need a deep understanding of the swift or objective - c. The answers to your question can't be given in a word. These are some of the understanding based on my experience.

All the best!

Comment: now im choosing swift

Comment: floor plans are keep as simple image file such as jpeg or bmp file. as per your suggention how it use dijikstra algorithm in simple images. i know that algoritham but how to implements in siomple image

Comment: @Araf you have to write on your own based on your requirements. You can ask for any code related issues here. Can't ask the whole functionality of your projects. Refer some sites and try it on your own. If you have any issues or doubts on the code you write, we are here to help!

Comment: Which technique used t0 plot paths on map . if plot a path with graphics  as sub layer for  map layout then how it manage on scaling time.

Comment: @Araf you need the coordinates of the starting and ending position and you have to write the algorithm to traverse through the valid coordinates in between the two points and draw the path using `CAShapeLayer`. For scaling, you have to customize the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods.

Comment: I also have one doubt . if user is get navigator start from o single room corner that time i have adjacent point on next room coordinates.  then how to navigate the user to current to position  to our defined position inside the room

Comment: @Araf it won't happen like that, beacon-based navigation has some limitations and it won't act like a gps. Are you working on navigation on a floor layout or inside a room? Because both are a different scenario.

Comment: i know that. i hope you don't get my point.

Comment: you need navigation between two points if the starting and ending points at two different rooms.right?

Comment: For eg: I am staying inside a shop and need to go to another shop.My doubts is, where should I start the navigation since I am showing only the predefined path.

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: It should be on the entrance point of the shop(start) to another entrance point of the shop(end).

Comment: @PraveenKumar Hi. could you share your project so I could use it as an example? Would highly appreciate!

Comment: @Araf Hi did you make it work? I am facing the same problem and looking for a solution, would be grateful if you would share your what you ve done so far. thanks

Comment: yes, We are  use game scenekit to draw map and you action. There have path finding sdk to find by using graph

Comment: @Araf can you say in more detail?

Comment: What kind of details you want?

Comment: @Araf suppose i have a floor plan. Should I use an image of the floor plan or should I draw it ? If you are drawing the floor plan, what are you using to draw ? And where do you get the data to draw it from ? Do you load from JSON ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, which solution is the best to place a floor plan image on top of google maps? We found some restrictions in term of image resolution that we still can't explain what are the google maps overlay (this is what we used) restrictions. Thanks